# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Docker Registry

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can one set the Pipeline so that Docker will pull images from a local registry?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found on a user [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/JPCTgbPlzHU) but I did not see this in the official docs.

For posterity sake here is the answer from the link

```
agent {
  docker {
    image "image name"
    registryUrl "https://wherever"
    registryCredentialsId "credsId"
  }
}
```

I tested this works with the most up to date plugin at time of writing.

Comment: That seems right, also seen in [JENKINS-39684](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39684). Sorry for being too fast and arrogant with my other answer (which I've deleted now).

Comment: No worries. Sorting out links/docs etc between the declarative and previous version is difficult.